# Will upsert work with array Elements as well as the normal ID in MongoDB through Java driver

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

Mongo DB contains the following data:

The requirement is if inside this document an Field exists incremnt the counter else insert the field.
Generally we use upsert for situations when we are not sure if its going to be insert or Update.But will this work with 
array Elements as well

db.arrayexample.find()

```
{ "_id" : "userID", "addresses" : [  {  "arrayid" : NumberLong(16694),  "count" : 12 } ] }
```

My Java code is as follows:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
MongoDatabase mongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("testdb3");
MongoCollection mongoCollection = mongoDatabase.getCollection("arrayexample");
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("_id", "userID");
query.put("addresses.arrayid",Long.valueOf(16695) );
    mongoCollection.findOneAndUpdate(query,new Document("$inc", new Document("addresses.$.count", 1)),new FindOneAndUpdateOptions().upsert(true));
```

I am getting the following error when i run the Program:

'exception: Cannot apply the positional operator without a corresponding query field containing an array.' on server localhost:27017. The full response is

```
 "value" : null, "errmsg" : "exception: Cannot apply the positional operator without a corresponding query field containing an array.", "code" : 16650,
```

Will $Upset work with array Elements as well as the normal ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, upserts will not work when using the $positional operator, as noted in the MongoDB documentation.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#upsert

Edit: As some flavour, it appears that there is an open feature request to support this particular kind of update when combined with the $setOnInsert operator within MongoDB's Jira https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-10711